# java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect

Tags: servlets, struts

I am using WAS 7 server, struts 1.2 and after deploying EAR to the server getting below exception:

```
org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init> Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.util.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
[2/20/13 5:10:24:048 PST] 00000016 PropertyMessa I org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init> Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.action.ActionResources', returnNull=true
[2/20/13 5:10:45:283 PST] 00000016 **ActionServlet E org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet handleConfigException Parsing error processing resource path 
                                 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect**
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:352)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:214)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:530)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:480)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:169)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:406)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:541)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:245)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:318)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:335)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:783)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:724)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:649)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:972)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1006)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
```

Also I am warning on the struts-config.xml file that **“The file cannot be validated as there was a connection problem.”**  while validating.

Any suggestion why I am getting ths error?

Comment: Please let me know any suggestions for this exceptions...

Comment: In `struts-config.xml`, system will try to validate the XML using the **DTD** URLs you had given. Check the URLs are proper and you are able to access them from the browser.